# Print file name if value less than specific number from multiple files in Linux

Tags: awk

I have a multiple files like below:all format is the same.

```
> Calss1.txt
No grade
1     93
2     45
3     66

> Calss2.txt
No grade
1     91
2     99
3     76
```

I want to find name of file which have any grade less than 60 then output to another file.
For exameple desird will like:

```
> output
Calss1.txt
```

I have tried like:

````
cat .txt | awk '{if($2==$2+0 && $2<50)print ```???```}'
````

I have noidea about how to print file name under condition.
Any tip is appreciate.Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU Awk, you can use the built-in variable `FILENAME` to print the currrent input file's name on the first matching of your criteria, then jump to the next input file with `nextfile`:

```bash
awk 'FNR>1 && $2<50 {print FILENAME; nextfile}' Class*.txt
```

```
Class1.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk:

```
awk 'FNR==1{x=1; next} x && $2<50 {print FILENAME; x=0; nextfile}' Class*.txt
```

If your awk supports `nextfile` (e.g. GNU) it'll be more efficient than if your awk doesn't support it but it'll work either way.